# How can you search for Closed Questions?

Tags: discussion

Is there a way to search for closed questions like you can search for a particular tag? Searching for the word 'closed' yields open questions and I'm not sure catches all the questions with "[closed]" in title. Searching for "[closed]" returns nothing leading me to believe closed is a meta-tag of some sort. Can it be searched for directly?

The answer was provided by @Fortiter and @Luke. Thank you. To find closed questions, search for

> closed:1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try searching for closed:1. Information obtained from [Find all questions on the Stack Exchange network that have been closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147249/find-all-questions-on-the-stackexchange-network-that-have-been-closed)

I have no idea what the value :1 represents; but it seems to work.

Comment: 'closed:1' is simply a convention to indicate a switch; that is to say "closed=yes" and 'closed:0' would indicate questions that are *not* closed. No, it's not the most obvious nomenclature... designed primarily by technical folks, but so are most *power user* functions.

Answer (score 5):

Type `@` into the search bar. It will give you a list of [advanced search options](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/search?q=@). In it, we find many entries. Here is the most relevant:

> questions that have been closed                      `closed:1` apples oranges
>
> (or not)                                                              `closed:0` apples oranges

Play around with it. It is very helpful for narrowing down search results. I found this by accident one day when I had nothing better to do with my time (okay, maybe I did). But, it has helped me out quite a bit. Especially for gathering statistics.